# Hello 10 instead of Hello world. Passing a IntPtr to printf (go - LLIR/LLVM)

Tags: go, llvm

I,
I'm new to LLIR/LLVM Based on the example Hello Word, I'd like to pass other types of variables (like int here). The following program crashes at line 25 with the error `invalid gep source type; expected pointer or vector of pointers type, got *types.IntType`. Could someone help me?

```
package irgen

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/llir/llvm/ir"
    "github.com/llir/llvm/ir/constant"
    "github.com/llir/llvm/ir/types"
)

func TestIntGEN(*testing.T) {
    // Create a new LLVM IR module.
    m := ir.NewModule()
    hello := constant.NewCharArrayFromString("Hello, %d!\n\x00")
    ten := constant.NewInt(types.I32, 10)
    str := m.NewGlobalDef("str", hello)
    // Add external function declaration of printf.
    printf := m.NewFunc("printf", types.I32, ir.NewParam("", types.NewPointer(types.I8)))
    printf.Sig.Variadic = true
    main := m.NewFunc("main", types.I32)
    entry := main.NewBlock("")
    // Cast *[15]i8 to *i8.
    zero := constant.NewInt(types.I64, 0)
    tenPtr := constant.NewGetElementPtr(ten.Typ, ten, zero, zero)
    gep := constant.NewGetElementPtr(hello.Typ, str, zero, zero)
    entry.NewCall(printf, gep, tenPtr)
    entry.NewRet(constant.NewInt(types.I32, 0))
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

---

I modified my code. It compiles but the result is not what is expected:

```
func TestIntGEN(*testing.T) {
    // Create a new LLVM IR module.
    m := ir.NewModule()
    hello := constant.NewCharArrayFromString("Hello, %d!\n\x00")
    ten := constant.NewInt(types.I32, 10)
    numb := m.NewGlobalDef("ten", ten)
    str := m.NewGlobalDef("str", hello)
    // Add external function declaration of printf.
    printf := m.NewFunc("printf", types.I32, ir.NewParam("", types.NewPointer(types.I8)))
    printf.Sig.Variadic = true
    main := m.NewFunc("main", types.I32)
    entry := main.NewBlock("")
    // Cast *[15]i8 to *i8.
    zero := constant.NewInt(types.I64, 0)
    // allocate memory for ten
    tenPtr := entry.NewAlloca(numb.Typ)
    // store the pointer to ten in tenPtr
    entry.NewStore(numb, tenPtr)
    gep := constant.NewGetElementPtr(hello.Typ, str, zero, zero)
    entry.NewCall(printf, gep, tenPtr)
    entry.NewRet(constant.NewInt(types.I32, 0))
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

It looks like the pointer is accessing a random value instead. Someone could help?

The resulting LLVM-IR is:

```
@ten = global i32 10
@str = global [12 x i8] c"Hello, %d!\0A\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8* %0, ...)

define i32 @main() {
0:
        %1 = alloca i32*
        store i32* @ten, i32** %1
        %2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr ([12 x i8], [12 x i8]* @str, i64 0, i64 0), i32** %1)
        ret i32 0
}
```